# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{k+1}\log(n_{k+1})} $ convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

For an arbitrary monotone subsequence $\{n_k\}\subset \mathbb{N}^+$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty}n_k = +\infty$. Does $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{k+1}\log(n_{k+1})} $$ convergent or not? Thanks very much.

Comment: No, take $n_k=k$ for instance

Comment: Hint. If you want to feel the behavior of your sum then try $n_k:=k^{\alpha}$. Then choose log and exp functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This series may be convergent and may be not:

- L.F's comment gives a sequence $n_k=k$ where the series is divergent since in this case
  $$\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{k+1}\log(n_{k+1})}=\frac{1}{(k+1)\log(k+1)}$$
  and we show easily the divergence of the series by the integral test.
- By the sequence $n_k=\lfloor e^{k^2}\rfloor$ we have
  $$\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{k+1}\log(n_{k+1})}\leq\frac{1}{\log(e^{(k+1)^2}-1)}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$$
  so it's a convergent series by comparison with the Riemann convergent series.

Comment: That you gave the OP the possibility of existing each cases(Div, Con) should be appreciated my brother, Sami. Finding these simple examples would take time, if I wanted to solve this :+)